# smarty accessing variables with double colon

Tags: php, smarty

Smarty's `{debug}` output has a value `pub-id::doi` that I need to access:

```
{foo} PublishedArticle Object  
 ->_data = Array  
...  
    pub-id::doi => "10.5334/aa.12302"  
...
```

but have no idea how because the key contains a double colon.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/advanced.features.static.classes.tpl)

if `doi` is a constant you can assign it a smarty variable by doing the following

```
{assign var=foo value=pub-id::doi}
```

if `doi` is a member variable of a class

```
{assign var=foo value=pub-id::$doi}
```

Comment: did you try putting `backquote` around it

Comment: yes - then all I get is "pub-id::". What I'm after is an access something like: {$foo->_data.pubid_doi} or similar

Comment: try `$foo._data.pubid::doi`

Comment: no luck there either, loads of `USER ERROR`s. I've tried countless variations now.